# Visual Studio default resource manager view

Tags: visual-studio

Every time I open the resource manager in Visual Studio it defaults to 'View In List' when I select Icons but to 'View As Thumbnails' when I select Images.

Anyone found a way to default Images to 'View In List' as well?

Comment: Many parts of Visual Studio are not customizable. I think you just hit another.

Comment: What topics can I ask about here?
- software tools commonly used by programmers;